# Python, search list of list and give next value

Tags: python, list, element

I'm creating a program that given a percentage for commission and given an invoice(s), it will look for given invoices, look for the value of that invoice and calculate the commission based on the percentage input. When we input `"calculate"` it will sum all the commission and give me the total of commission.

I'm having trouble trying to identify the input within the list. Once I do that, what must I do to be given the value of that invoice?

`data base = [Invoice, Invoice amount, invoice margin]`

This is what I have so far.

```
data_base = [["f1",2000,.24],["f2",150000,.32],["f3",345000,.32]]
comission_percentage = int(input("Comision Percentage: "))
invoice = input("Enter an invoice: ")
total_comision = 0


while invoice != "calculate" :
    while invoice in data_base:
        invoice_ = data_base.index(invoice)+1 #Gives me the position of invoice
        invoice_amount = data_base[p_factura] #Give me the value os the invoice
        comission = ((margen_comisionar/100)* monto_factura) #calculatecomission
        total_comision = comission + total_comission         
        invoice = input("Enter an invoice: ")
print("The amount to comission is: " + str(total_comission))
```

Comment: what issue are you facing? getting data from list?

Comment: you should try this code. check for the names and indentation 

        total = 0
        invoice  = "calculate"
        while invoice!='calculate'
              for item in data_base:
                    total = total + item[1]*comission_percentage/100
                    invoice = input("Enter invoice: ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do better to split up the task of finding the right invoice from the calculations.

At present your code will not run at all, as you are using variables whose values you haven't defined. Since you don't need to alter the invoices at all it will be fine just to return the values you want. Here's an example, that returns an "empty" invoice in case it doesn't find the one you asked for:

```
def find_invoice(s):
    for i_num, amount, rate in data_base:
        if i_num == s:
            return i_num, amount, rate
    return(None, 0.0, 0,0)
```

Then the main part of your logic can read:

```
total_commission = 0.0
while invoice != "calculate":
    i, amt, rate = find_invoice(invoice)
    if i:
        total_commission += amt*comission_percentage/100.0
        invoice = input("Enter an invoice: ")
```

Also, be careful with variable names. Your spelling must be EXACT! Not a bad effort for an apparent beginner, though.

Comment: Ok. I understood. I'm getting an error if I search for a value that is not within the database. If its not included, it should ask me for another input.

Comment: and if I state in de the def function that when not in data bese re-ask, but then I cant end the program with calculate

Answer (score 0):

Your 'database' seems to be a list of lists.  I'm assuming the input from the user is supposed to match the first part of the list.

So given:

```
data_base = [["f1",2000,.24],["f2",150000,.32],["f3",345000,.32]]
```

If the user inputs `f1`, you want it to match `["f1",2000,.24]`.

Your inner `while` loop will not work in this case since `"f1"` is not in `[["f1",2000,.24],["f2",150000,.32],["f3",345000,.32]]`

You need to check if the first element of every element of your list matches your input.

```
for invoice_info in database:
    if invoice in invoice_info:
       # found it!
       <do your invoice commission calculations here>
```

A better way to do it would be to convert your database to dictionaries:

```
data_base = {'f1': {'invoice_amount': 2000, 'invoice_margin': .24},
             'f2': {'invoice_amount': 15000, 'invoice_margin': .32},
             'f3': {'invoice_amount': 345000, 'invoice_margin': .32}
             }
```

Then you can do

```
if invoice in data_base:
    found_invoice = data_base[invoice]
    total_commission += found_invoice['invoice_amount'] * commission_percentage / 100
```

Comment: Ok. the purpose of this program is to be able to import from a data base. If I were to do that. how would the information look like in python?

Comment: I really can't tell what that would look like.  There are lots of ways of interfacing with databases in python and many of them act differently.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code. check for the names and indentation

```
        total = 0
        invoice  = "calculate"
        while invoice!='calculate'
            for item in data_base:
                  total = total + item[1]*comission_percentage/100
                  invoice = input("Enter invoice: ")
```